# Unofficial way to run 16 bits custom Windows Installer on Windows 64 bits

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, 16-bit, windows-10-v1903

I’ve a old proprietary custom Installer that Windows can’t convert to a 32 bits one (the 32 bits program installed requires the processing power of a powerfull ɢᴘᴜ in order to be run correctly so full emulation isn’t an option).
So running the Installer like any Win16 bits app is required…

**I’m fully aware the official Microsoft answer is `you can’t`**.
But the unofficial answer is Wine has no problem running the Installer on 64 bits Linux (but the Direct3d to OpenGl conversion bite performance of the installed 32 bits program) (such an irony where Linux runs Windows programs better than Microsoft).
**The reason is vm86 mode isn’t needed for Windows 16 bits, but only 16 bits segment support through the [local descriptor table](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html)**. It seems in reality Microsoft has no reason to put the effort into changing the way they do.

So what’s the unofficial way to perform this without having to use Wine to run Installed program ?

Comment: You should be rewriting the installer to work under 32/64 bits. Windows has been 32 bits or more since Window NT (released in 1993). Why are you insisting on using 16 bit code written for an operating system more than 25 years old?

Comment: Windows in VM is your only solution, if you want to run it on Windows 10. Boot directly into Windows 32-bit 7 if otherwise.

Comment: @DavidPostill You see the problem with the installer is the company which created the source code was closed on acquisition. The installer itself was created in 1997 while the program was created in 2003. I don’t know how the security keys used to check the license are built : I need the installer for it.

Comment: @user2284570 Are you aware if the software itself (not the installer) is 32-bit? If so, I _might_ just be able to help.

Comment: @rahuldottech It’s because there’s no install.inf on the cd Windows fails to recognize `Setup.exe` is an installer.

Comment: @user2284570 Will you be able to share an image of the cd?

Comment: Is it DOS based?

Comment: @CanadianLuke they mention a GUI

Comment: @rahuldottech There are DOS programs with a GUI

Comment: @CanadianLuke not it’s Win16 based and it’s because Win16 share the same Windows registry than 32 bits that It works. The resulting installation is dependent of the hardware : you need to reinstall if you do something like changing drive letters or installed ram (though ram is amount is truncated to 32 bits). I recognize this is an efficient practice against file sharing (though might be trivial to reverse engineer). The way such high ɢᴘᴜ power is required is because I want modern resolution with modern framerate (something you wouldn’t had done back in 2003).

Comment: @DavidPostill Same kind of question about why does Boeing uses an Intel 286 clone on the 737 max I suppose. And what about a [port of the wine version of ɴᴛᴠᴅᴍ on Native Windows](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[otvdm is the unofficial replacement of Ntvdm I was looking for](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm). While 16 bits Windows uses protected mode, and thus doesn’t require real mode accessing at all unlike Microsoft is claiming (the requirement is 16‑bits segments access).
It emulates the ᴄᴘᴜ either completely like Ntᴠᴅᴍ or through [Intel Haxm](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows) for better performance, but it does so just in order to wrap Syscalls like Wine would do on Linux : no virtual Network card ; no Virtual hard disk (`%systemdrive%` is `%systemdrive%`) ; no allocated but unused memory ; and there’s the option I’m looking for but which is disabled by default : **that changes written to the registry is done to the one of the system !**

It’s even more powerful than the official Ntᴠᴅᴍ : the transparent level of hardware access is so high that It should be possible to use the full processing power of original graphics hardware. Though there were no ᴀᴘɪ for doing that at that time…

Like Ntᴠᴅᴍ, it’s launched transparently and automatically when a 16 bits program is encountered.
The only bad point is the Windows 3.11 userland like the Program Manager isn’t included with this version (not even an open‑source clone of it) whereas even modern Windows 32‑bits Windows 10 contains it. But as it’s about exe, it should be possible to just copy from a 32 bits Windows in order to get them.

It can be downloaded pre‑compiled [here](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm/releases/download/v0.7.0/otvdm-v0.7.0.zip).